# jquery infinite scrolling - block multiple calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, infinite-scroll

i have a paginated website and i'm loading the next page once the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. i'm using jquery's `.on('scroll', this.detectScroll())` binding scrolling to a function that checks where in the page the user currently is and loads the next page if they reached the bottom.

```
detectScroll: function() {
    var controller = this;

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height();
        var scrollEnd = $(document).height();

        var distance = scrollEnd - scrolled; // distance from page edge

        if (distance === 0) { 
            controller.loadPage();
        }
    });

}
```

the problem is, since the scroll event happens so often, the function gets called multiple times before the next page is loaded and the result is that many pages are loaded and appended to the view at the same time.

i tried unbinding the event in the `loadPage()` function, but i think the scroll event listener gets called faster than the function starts so it doesn't work. here's the function that's responsible for loading the next page:

```
loadPage: function () {
    this.currentPage++;
    $(window).off("scroll");

    $.ajax({
        url: this.settings.pageUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            page: this.currentPage
        },
        success: $.proxy(function(result) {
            // once new page inserted, start listening again
            if(result != "") {
                this.$view.append(result); // insert new page into view
                this.detectScroll();
            } 


        }, this),
        error: $.proxy(function(result) {
            // error
            this.$userContainer.html('<h3 class="text-center">Error loading content...</h3>');
        }, this)
    });
},
```

i tried unbinding the listener immediately after `loadPage()` gets loaded and binding it again in the callback but it didn't work either. i think the best solution would be to only listen to scroll events in a certain interval - say, only listen every 200ms. this would prevent multiple firing of the same function. but i couldn't find anything on that online, so please give me some tips.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _xhr = []; // global

loadPage: function () {
    this.currentPage++;
    $(window).off("scroll");

    [].forEach.call(_xhr, function(i, j){
       i.abort();
       _xhr.splice(j, 1);
    });

    var x = $.ajax({
        url: this.settings.pageUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            page: this.currentPage
        },
        success: $.proxy(function(result) {
            // once new page inserted, start listening again
            if(result != "") {
                this.$view.append(result); // insert new page into view
                this.detectScroll();
            } 


        }, this),
        error: $.proxy(function(result) {
            // error
            this.$userContainer.html('<h3 class="text-center">Error loading content...</h3>');
        }, this)
    });
    _xhr.push(x);
},
```

Keep all the request in an array, then before making any new request just `.abort` all previous request and pop them from the array.